# Get Last email from thread and fetch csv attachment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I an trying to get last email thread csv attachment ID but I am having difficulties working out the code. Anyone able to help?

```
var searcher = "Automail-"+CurrentDateFormat+".csv";

var searchedThreads = GmailApp.search( 'subject:""'+searcher+'""')[0];

var id = searchedThreads.getId(); 
var dateMessage = GmailApp.getMessageById(id).getDate();
var contentmessage = GmailApp.getMessageById(id).getPlainBody();

var attachtextLength = GmailApp.getMessageById(id).getAttachments()[0].getDataAsString().length;
if (attachtextLength >= 150){

var attachtext = GmailApp.getMessageById(id).getAttachments()[0].getDataAsString();

UpdateSheet(attachtext);
```

Comment: What is the difficulty? What errors do you get?

Comment: As the code is at the moment I am able to get the attachment but only from the 1st email, not for the last email.

Comment: Well what happens? try inserting debugging statements to check values of various variables. can you fetch any other info from the second email or nothing at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the last thread matched of multiple threads....

```
var searchedThreads = GmailApp.search( 'subject:""'+searcher+'""');
searchedThreads = searchedThreads[searchedThreads.length-1];
```

If you are looking for the last attachment ....

```
var attachtext = GmailApp.getMessageById(id).getAttachments();
attachtext = attachtext[attachtext.length-1].getDataAsString();
```

Hope it helps.